# Query for selecting a phone number from the contact list

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number

I have a problem with query in Android.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

I put permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
String contactNumber = "";

if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri contctDataVar = data.getData();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(contctDataVar, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
        if(hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID, null, null );
            if(phones.moveToFirst()){
                contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`contactName` is ok, but

```
Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID, null, null );
```

Not working, the application will be closed.What it wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying all phone numbers of a contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798639/querying-all-phone-numbers-of-a-contact)

Comment: I try this cod but nothing, the "phoneNumber" is empty

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete code for get contact number

```
Cursor phones = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while (phones.moveToNext())
{
    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
}
phones.close();
```

Comment: Did you checked the run time permission of contacts (for marshmallow and above)?